# How do I make an SSL-secured reverse proxy on Nginx with Let's Encrypt?

Tags: node.js, ssl, nginx, proxy

I have a RestAPI that works on Node.js and it's proxied through Nginx with the following configuration (private parts have been hidden):

```
   server {

    listen 80;
    server_name mywebsitestuff.com www.mywebsitestuff.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://serverip:25000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I want this API work with a Let's Encrypt SSL Certificate, how can I do it?
*Thanks*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.use Let's encrypt to sign a cert for you domain `mywebsitestuff.com www.mywebsitestuff.com`

Links: [Getting Started - Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/)

2.config the server block like this

```
listen 443;
server_name   mywebsitestuff.com;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate     /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsitestuff.com/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsitestuff.com/privkey.pem;
ssl_protocols       TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
```

*You might need to sign two certs for your domain both w/ and w/o www, then config them in two separate server block since they are using two different certs.*

UPDATE：

It seems like Let's Encrypt will visit `/.well-known/acme-challenge/` for authentication of domain.

Add a location to avoid reverse proxy this request like this

```
location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
    root /some/path/;
}
```

Then you can continue on with webroot plugin with command like

`./path/to/certbot-auto certonly --webroot -w /some/path -d mywebsitestuff.com -d www.mywebsitestuff.com`

Make sure `/some/path` exists and you can write while nginx can read.

Comment: Hey thanks! When I have to create the certificate I have to specify a location for the webroot plugin, what should I put in?

Comment: With the Reverse proxy, I mean. I know that with a normal website I'd put the directory of the website.